# How do I install/configure install Google's PageSpeed Module on cPanel (not WHM) and/or via PuTTY?

Tags: page-speed, google-pagespeed

My setup:

- Shared hosting plan on SiteGround.
- cPanel from SiteGround (Not WHM... whatever that is)
- Windows 10
- PuTTY (installed, logged into my cPanel username: 
  [image: PuTTY logged in]

I've found and read through various tutorials, used my Google-fu, and I'm coming up short. Most of the tutorials I find are using cPanel WHM (eg. https://github.com/pagespeed/cpanel) which I do not have, or at least I haven't figured out how to access. The path they are using "usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty" does not exist when I use the cd command to go there in PuTTY (/usr/local/cpanel does exist).

I'd really like to get mod_pagespeed up and running if possible. I'm fairly new to SSH, so more detail than less will be useful.

So you know what I am working with, here is a link to the Google PageSpeed insights for my website: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lemonly.co

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather simple.... you can't.

Shared hosting even with SSH enabled does not give the necessary permissions to install new server-side processes because your actions could affect their security or the performance of the server that will ultimate affect everyone on it. The SSH provided to you as apart of cPanel for non-administrators is for administrating of files and folders, e.g:

- `vi access.log` viewing logs
- `chmod`: changing file and directory permissions
- `wget`: downloading remote files
- `tar, unzip` decompressing files
- `mkdir` creating directories
- `rm` removing files or directories

*It does not support `su root`, `sudo`, `yum` or `install`.*

If you want to install mod_pagespeed or any other 3rd party module for Apache then you need to upgrade to a dedicated or virtual environment that allows such freedom of control ~ shared hosting is designed for simple hosting and not advanced server-side modification.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I got in touch with SiteGround support today, and they have an off the shelf mod_pagespeed application you can install via their GUI. But, it's only available if you have at a minimum the Grow Big plan they offer, which is roughly double the cost of the most basic plan.